# how to create multiple login access in yii2?

Tags: authentication, yii2, yii-components

I am creating a site in Yii2 and using basic version.
I want have two login with two tables but suppose there is an Id for logged in user is 1 and same id belongs from other table for admin user than Yii takes both identity and it show two logout button one for admin user and other for normal user but it should show only one logout and Yii should keep identity for that particular controller/login. Please help what can i do.

```
// login admin module
'user' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\User',
                'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
                'enableAutoLogin' => true,

        ],
// login site   
    'marketer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Marketer',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl' => 'test/index',
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_marketer', 
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: I don't think you really need two user _identities_. You should have one user _identity_ (a login-password pair) and assign multiple _roles_ (user and marketer) to that identity. This is done using [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac).

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the [Advanced Application Template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html). With it you actually have two applications which can use different models(tables) for login.

I recommend checking out Kartik's Application Templates:

- [Yii2 Practical App](http://demos.krajee.com/app-practical)
- [Yii2 Practical-A App](http://demos.krajee.com/app-practical-a)

They are based on the Advanced Application Template, but with some improvements.